# How to get transfer data from mirrored port without establishing TCP/IP connection on python socket?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, ip, scapy

I have one simple question: Can I sniff the mirrored packets as if I am accepting python socket?

I am receiving a file on Server A by using get_file_by_socket.py :

```
import socket
import tqdm
import os
import hashlib
import time

SERVER_HOST = "192.168.1.1"
SERVER_PORT = 5201
counter = 1
BUFFER_SIZE = 4096
SEPARATOR = "<SEPARATOR>"
s = socket.socket()
s.bind((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))
s.listen(5)
print(f"[*] Listening as {SERVER_HOST}:{SERVER_PORT}")
client_socket, address = s.accept()
print("client_scoket = ",client_socket,address)
print(f"[+] {address} is connected")
received = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()
filename,filesize = received.split(SEPARATOR)
filename = os.path.basename(filename)
filesize = int(filesize)
file_hash = hashlib.md5()
progress = tqdm.tqdm(range(filesize), f"Receiving {filename}", unit="B",unit_scale=True, unit_divisor=1024)
with open(filename,"wb") as f:
    while True:
        bytes_read = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if not bytes_read:
            break
        f.write(bytes_read)
        file_hash.update(bytes_read)
        print(f"{counter}. Bytes_read={bytes_read}")
        #print(f"{counter}. ")
        counter = counter + 1
        time.sleep(0.001)
        progress.update(len(bytes_read))

client_socket.close()
s.close()
```

I am sending the file using send_file_by_socket.py from Host B :

```
import socket
import tqdm
import os
import sys
SEPARATOR = "<SEPARATOR>"
BUFFER_SIZE = 4096
host = sys.argv[1]  #"192.168.1.1"
print("host=",host)
port = 5201
filename = sys.argv[2] #"twibot20.json" 
print("filename=",filename)
filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
s = socket.socket()
#s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,25,'enp2s0')
print(f"[+] Connecting to {host}:{port}")
s.connect((host,port))
print("[+] Connected.")
s.send(f"{filename}{SEPARATOR}{filesize}".encode())
progress = tqdm.tqdm(range(filesize), f"Sending {filename}", unit="B", unit_scale = True, unit_divisor=1024)
with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    while True :
        bytes_read = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if not bytes_read:
            break
        s.sendall(bytes_read)
        progress.update(len(bytes_read))
s.close()
```

The sender sends the file and the server receives it successfully. The transfer rate is quite high. Now I am mirroring the packets while the transfer is happening. I sniff the packets using sniff_mirrored_packets.py :

```
def get_if():
    ifs=get_if_list()
    iface=None
    for i in get_if_list():
        if "enp1s0f1" in i:
            iface=i
            break;
    if not iface:
        print("Cannot find eth0 interface")
        exit(1)
    return iface


def handle_pkt(pkt):
    global file_hash
    global counter
    try :
        setir = pkt[IP].load
    except :
        setir = ""
    if "<SEPARATOR>" in str(setir):
        setir = ""
    if setir!="" :
        file_hash.update(setir)
    print("{}. Hash = {} ".format(counter,file_hash.hexdigest()))
    #pkt.show2()
    sys.stdout.flush()
    counter = counter +1


def main():
    ifaces = [i for i in os.listdir('/sys/class/net/') ]
    iface = get_if()
    print(("sniffing on %s" % iface))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sniff(filter='tcp and port 5201',iface = iface,
          prn = lambda x: handle_pkt(x))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The problem is socket transfer rate is too high, that's why I included :

```
time.sleep(0.001)
```

on get_file_by_socket.py on the server-side, since sniffing speed on the mirror side is too slow. When I send a 3MB file from Host B, I get around 200 out of 1000 packets in the mirror-side using the tshark. When I time.sleep(0.001) on the server-side, only then I do receive all 1000 packets on the mirror-side.

My questions are:

1. How do I get transfer data from mirrored port without establishing TCP/IP handshake python socket? Can I get the mirrored packets the same as on get_file_by_socket.py by ignoring TCP handshake which is happening between Host B and Server A. (I implemented get_file_by_socket.py like code on the mirror-side but it stuck in handshake because the mirrored packets don't have any handshake in it). The sniffing method that I am using is too slow in comparison with socket transfer rate.
2. What other methods can be used to catch up with the socket transfer rate?

Comment: First, this is not "one simple question." :-) Second, Python is the wrong language for this type of task. You'll need a much more performant language such as Go or C++.

Comment: Please remove tag scapy if there's no link with it.

Comment: I am sniffing using scapy sniff. @qouify

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning, I couldn’t capture all the packets mirrored since some packets were dropped in the kernel. I could sniff it only after increasing the kernel buffer size by:

```
sudo tcpdump -s 65535 -v -i enp1s0f1 -nn -B 424096 -w dtn4.pcap
```

After capturing all the packets I am post-processing to build the final version of the text file.

Regarding sniffing the socket without handshake, I couldn't find anything.